# Integrate solr into an existing project

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I want to integrate Solr to an existing Javaweb project, but use it without starting a Solr service, like manipulating files with java.io.

The code maybe like this:

```java
Solr solr = new Solr(path_of_solr_data);    // Specify Solr's data directory
SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
...
solr.add(document);
solr.commit()
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: what is without starting the solr service? check if you can use Lucene instead in solr

Comment: The [EmbeddedSolrServer is still available](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_5_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer.html), but not recommended.

Comment: @MatsLindh this is what I'm looking for, thanks a lot